# Codeigniter - convert mysql query to CodeIgniter's active record query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, subquery

I'm trying to convert this SQL query into a codeigniter query

```
SELECT 
  uploads.EMAIL
FROM
  uploads 
  JOIN (

    SELECT EMAIL, COUNT(*) as num FROM uploads GROUP BY EMAIL
  ) c ON uploads.EMAIL = c.EMAIL
ORDER BY 
  c.num DESC, 
  EMAIL ASC
```

Thanks for the help
kind regards

Comment: What do you mean by "codeigniter query"? Do you mean like using its Active Record class?

Comment: Yes. Im unsure how to do sub queries sorry English not so good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you can't figure this out yourself using the [active record documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html), but:

```
$this->db->select('uploads.EMAIL');
$this->db->from('uploads');
$this->db->join('(SELECT EMAIL, COUNT(*) as num FROM uploads GROUP BY EMAIL) c','uploads.EMAIL = c.EMAIL','',FALSE);
$this->db->order_by('c.num desc, uploads.EMAIL asc');
```

and then

```
$query = $this->db->get();
```

FYI, passing FALSE as the fourth parameter to the `db->join()` method will cause it not to escape the statement, so you should be careful if you're going to take external variables. This is, until CodeIgniter 3, the only way to do subqueries with active record without extending the active record class to add them.